# AWS IOT multiple device connection at the same time problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, esp8266

I successfully integrated ESP8266 01 and AWS IOT core. It's working fine. But when I tried to connect second device then the first connection got closed.

To fix the issue I tried the followings:

1. different things
2. different certificates
3. different topics

But these not helped to fix my problem.

Another thing is that each and every thing shows the same endpoint.

So how to connect multiple devices at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's my mistake to use the same client id for all. Fixed after assigning unique client-id to each.